# Using groups in mercurial's allow_read, allow_push etc

Tags: authentication, mercurial, authorization

I was wondering if it is possible to use groups specified in e.g., an apache authgroup file in allow_read and/or allow_push etc.

So basically what I do is I am using apache with an authfile and authgroup file to authenticate users.
Now I want to restrict some repositories using allow_read from being shown to users in a specific group specified in the authgroup file.

Let's say I have sam, frodo and sauron in my auth file and I have a group hobbits containing sam and frodo in the authgroup file.

So instead of writing:

allow_read = frodo, sam

I tried

allow_read = @hobbits

but that does not seem to work. Does anybody know whether this is actually supported? The idea is if I have say 10 Repositories only readable for hobbits and I add a hobbit I only have to change the authgroup and auth file and not each repository hgrc file.

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial does not have any builtin support for groups. There is a patch from a user that adds group support, but the coders seemed hesitant to include it by default, they want the contributor to make a plugin out of it instead. As of April 2013 they [seem to have accepted it](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/PATCH-hgweb-add-group-authorization-td3998103.html), but I still see no trace of it in the version currently shipped with Ubuntu (2.7).

Controlling groups in Apache, as suggested by Joel, doesn't give you any fine granular control when you have more than one repository, so it's no use (at least not for me).

I ended up using the open source tool [SCM-Manager](http://www.scm-manager.org/) for it. SCM-Manager acts as a frontend for SVN, Git and Mercurial and has support for various user directories (including LDAP and Crowd) as well as its own user directory.

I'm using mod_proxy to integrate it in my Apache configuration and it works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you'll need to do your group controlling in Apache rather than in `hgrc` files, as the [documentation for `hgrc`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#web) mentions only user names.

You'll want to have a read of [Configuring Apache](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Configuring_Apache) on the Publishing Repositories page. Section **7.4** seems to contain the information you'll need to set up what you want.

Comment: not quite what I need I'm afraid. For instance, let's say I have 2 repositories whereas the first one should only be seen and accessible by _hobbits_ and the second one only by _nonhobbits_. Since with apache and say _LimitExcept_ I can only control the access methods _GET_, _POST_ etc. for the repository page not for each repository

Comment: The reason I thought it would be helpful is that there are examples there that indicate you'll need to split your *hobbits* and *nonhobbits* repos into entirely separate directories with their own configs (7.4.4 was the strongest clue). Wouldn't restrictions to one directory affect access to repos under that directory?

Comment: I suppose restriction to one directory might affect access to repos. But the problem is that the _hobbit_ _nonhobbit_ group problem is a very simplified example of the constalations I might encounter. So as I said for me it would be the easiest to have group support in the web section of the _hgrc_ file of a repository. But it seems that is not possible right now.